# Can users with over 2000 rep suggest edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, review

A lot of times I've seen a post and wanted to edit it, but I wasn't sure if it changed the original intent of the post, or would be helpful, so I held off, knowing that my edits would be binding unless someone edited them out or rolled back the changes.

In these situations, it would be great to be able to suggest an edit, to see if the rest of the community agrees with the edit. Instead of them having to *undo* a bad edit of mine, it would be better to have the edit rejected before it ever gets seen by other users. There are a few things that could be used in replacement for a >2k rep user suggesting edits, such as

- Editing it anyway, but writing in the edit summary "I'm not sure if this changes the meaning of the post"
- Asking about the potential edit in a comment
- Going on chat and asking about it there
- Open a new browser and suggest an edit anonymously

However, all of these seem like workarounds. I think it'd be nice to at least have the edit approved by one other person if you're unsure about it. Perhaps a button on the edit window saying "Do you want this edit to go into the queue"?

Comment: If you're 50/50 on whether it's correct, you can be sure it'd get approved either way...

Comment: To answer the title only: yes, on tag wikis, if below 5k rep. To answer the actual question: you could add a comment asking for others to double check your edit if you're not confident about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Once you obtain 2000 rep, you gain the ability to edit posts directly, and your ability to suggest edits (and earn the rep they confer) is removed.

Suggested edits are training wheels; once you've learned how to make edits properly, you should make them yourself, and rely on the community to roll them back if they disagree with your edit.